# JSP Param object to string

Tags: java, jsp

I want to send a string to a function defined in jsp taglib. Specifically, I want to send a param that I'm getting in the page.
i.e. Here the second parameter should be a string. If I use ${param.username} it gives an error, probably because ${param.username} is an object and not a string
${insert:insert(5,)}

Comment: A parameter is always a string. If we had the code which causes the exception, and the message and stack trace of this exception, we could provide help. Error messages are intended to be read and help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: It doesn't compile. The syntax error is encountered "{" at line 1 column 20. Was expecting one of "."... ")"...   When I put "" instead of ${param.username}, It works perfectly

Comment: And what is the code at line 1, causing this compilation error?

Comment: ${insert:insert(5,${param.username})}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed an EL expression (`${...}`) inside another EL expression (`${...}`). You just need

```
${insert:insert(5, param.username)}
```